# Zxing problems with scanner

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a qr code reader but when I start the scanner it shows as a barcode reader.

These are the properties of my scanner

```
private fun initScanner() {
        val integrator = IntentIntegrator(this@InicioActivity)
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE)
        integrator.setPrompt("Escaneé el código QR")
        integrator.setBeepEnabled(true)
        integrator.initiateScan()
    }
```

As you can see I tell it to be a qr.code but it ignores it

Thank you so much

I hope resolve this problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.